# Angular 2 Two Way binding between components using Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass an object from component to service and fetch by another component as an observable so that in the future when I change something in Question Component it updates the Service BUT currently the getQuestion() does not work for Question Component.

Service:

```
   selectedSurvey: any;
   setQuestion(passedObject){ 
   this.selectedSurvey=  passedObject;
   }

   getQuestion(): Observable<any>{
  return this.selectedSurvey;
   }
```

Survey Component

```
   private subscription: Subscription;
   survey: any;
  onChange(surveyObject) {
    this.surveyService.setQuestion(surveyObject);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription =  this.surveyService.getSurveys().subscribe( survey => {  this.survey = survey });

  }
```

Survey Component Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select Survey:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" id="selsurvey" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let s of survey" [value]="s">{{s.surveyName}}</option>

        </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Question Component

```
  private subscription: Subscription;
    survey: any;
   constructor(private surveyService: SurveyService) { }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.subscription =  this.surveyService.getQuestion().subscribe( survey => { console.log(survey),this.survey = survey })
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In service:

```
yourSubject:Subject<WhatevaTypeYouWant>=new Subject<WhatevaTypeYouWant>();
```

in producer

```
service.yourSubject.next(value);
```

in consumer

```
  service.yourSubject.subscribe(val=>{handler});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3anuot.

Check `child-component/child-component.ts`, `child-component/communication.service.ts` and `app.component.ts`.

Hope it helps